# Spark - Aggregate user activity to represent periods

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with a Spark DataFrame like the one below:

```
user | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... | 53
-------------------------------
   1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... |  1
   2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... |  0
   3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |  1
   .
   .
   .
   n | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | ... |  0
```

which has columns representing user ID, then a column for each week of the year containing a boolean, representing whether a user was active for that week.

My goal is to reduce this to a table like so:

```
user | active_start | active_end | duration
-------------------------------------------
   1 |            1 |          1 |        1
   1 |            4 |          4 |        1
   1 |           53 |         53 |        1
   2 |            2 |          4 |        3
   3 |            1 |          2 |        2
   3 |           53 |         53 |        1
   .
   .
   .
   n |            1 |          1 |        1
   n |            3 |          4 |        2
```

which contains periods of continuous activity.

I'm at somewhat of a loss as to how I should manipulate the table/aggregate the values so as to create a new row when a gap is detected.

I have tried using code for Island/Gap detection to generate these groups, but have been unable to implement a version which does not detect and generate rows for smaller sub-islands within larger ones.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another suggestion, also using `flatMap`, but with `foldLeft` inside to compute the intervals:

```scala
case class Interval(user: Int, active_start: Int, active_end: Int, duration: Int)

def computeIntervals(userId: Int, weeks: Seq[Int]): TraversableOnce[Interval] = {

  // First, we get the indexes where the value is 1
  val indexes: Seq[Int] = weeks.zipWithIndex.collect {
    case (value, index) if value == 1 => index
  }

  // Then, we find the "breaks" in the sequence (i.e. when the difference between indexes is > 1)
  val breaks: Seq[Int] = indexes.foldLeft((List[Int](), -1)) { (pair, currentValue) =>
    val (breaksBuffer: List[Int], lastValue: Int) = pair
    if ((currentValue - lastValue) > 1 && lastValue >= 0) (breaksBuffer :+ lastValue :+ currentValue, currentValue)
    else (breaksBuffer, currentValue)
  }._1

  // Then, we add the first and last indexes and re-organize in pairs
  val breakPairs = (indexes.head +: breaks :+ indexes.last).map(_ + 1).grouped(2)

  // Finally, we convert each pair to an interval and return
  breakPairs.map {
    case List(lower, upper) => Interval(userId, lower, upper, upper-lower+1)
  }
}
```

Running:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
  (3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  (4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
).toDF

import spark.implicits._

df.flatMap { row: Row => 
  val (userId, weeksAsSeq) = ((row.toSeq.head.asInstanceOf[Int], row.toSeq.drop(1).map(_.asInstanceOf[Int])))
  computeIntervals(userId, weeksAsSeq)
}.show

+----+------------+----------+--------+
|user|active_start|active_end|duration|
+----+------------+----------+--------+
|   1|           1|         1|       1|
|   1|           4|         5|       2|
|   2|           2|         4|       3|
|   3|           3|         3|       1|
|   3|           5|         5|       1|
|   4|           1|         2|       2|
|   4|           5|         5|       1|
+----+------------+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `flatMap` your df with a function to calculate your metrics for every row.

Then provide the column names to your new DF.

```
val newDf = yourDf
  .flatMap(row => {
    val userId = row.getInt(0)
    val arrayBuffer = ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]()
    var start = -1
    for (i <- 1 to 53) {
      val active = row.getInt(i)
      if (active == 1 && start == -1) {
        start = i
      }
      else if (active == 0 && start != -1) {
        val duration = i - start + 1
        val end = i - 1
        arrayBuffer.append((userId, start, end, duration))
        start = -1
      }
    }
    arrayBuffer
  })
  .toDF("user", "active_start", "active_end", "duration" )
```